# Play/pause Spotify desktop from web browser

Tags: javascript, spotify

I try to find the solution used in [bop.fm](http://bop.fm/) to control Spotify desktop application. 
I guess somehow uses some iframe "https://embed.spotify.com/remote-control-bridge/" 
Any idea? 
thank you very much

Comment: You should add detail to your post indicating what you have tried so far along with your results.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to use the spotify local server as explained here: http://cgbystrom.com/articles/deconstructing-spotifys-builtin-http-server/